# tryCatch to ignore error and go on failed. R stops computation

Tags: r

Hi guys I wrote a function that basically splits a large data.frame into two parts and then computes some calculations on each sub-data.frame. After such calculations it sums the computations result from each sub-data.frame row by row (the string: z = x+y).
A piece of the function:

> ```
> Myfun <- function(fileName,    
>                   check.names=FALSE, header = FALSE,   
>                    stringsAsFactor = FALSE,    
>                    sep = "\t",...){
>
> Data <- read.delim(fileName, 
>                   header = header,
>                  check.names = check.names, 
>                  stringsAsFactor = stringsAsFactor, sep = sep, ...)
>
>  newdata_a <- Data[which(Data[,1]==1), ]     
>  newdata_b <- Data[ which(Data[,1]==-1), ]        
>  ...............
>  ...............
>  z = x+y    
>  return(tryCatch((z), error=function(e) NULL))     
> }
> ```

I apply this function  on a set of data.frames using the following piece of code:

> ```
> source("Myfun.R")
> files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
> files = mixedsort(sort(files))
> for (i in 1: length(files)){
> b <- lapply(files, Myfun)}
> ```

The problem is that for some data.frames x and y have different length due to the nature of the data.frame and this is the reason why the following error message occurs:

> ```
> Error in Ops.data.frame(x, y) :     
>   + only defined for equally-sized data frames
>   Calls: lapply -> FUN -> Ops.data.frame
>   Execution halted
> ```

To overcome this problem I introduce the string: return(tryCatch((z), error=function(e) NULL)) into Myfun to allow R to go on and ignore the error, but the script stops anyway.

Comment: You have to put the `x+y` part inside of `tryCatch`, otherwise you're just catching its result and the error has already occurred.

Comment: Ok, thank you Thomas. I'm new! I' ll try soon!